# URLs from applications are not opened directly, but downloaded and then opened

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, firefox, kde

For example when I click a link in Hipchat or download new version button in  IntelliJ IDEA instead of directly opening the link, the page is downloaded and then opened. So I see a crippled, usually very broken page.

I can see in my browser this URL:

```
file:///home/xxx/.cache/kioexec/krun/6757_0_download
```

I am using Waterfox, but I think exactly same problem was with Firefox.

How to force KDE (or whatever messes this up) to not download pages, but open them as it got them?

Answer (score 1):

I recently have a similar problem I managed to fix it by changing default browser.

Remember to do it through the settings not from the browser it self